# What is the use of tf.keras.backend nowadays, is it safer/more future proof to code w/ or w/o it?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I understand the historical need for `keras.backend` in the long gone days of multiframework support. But now that we are talking about `tf.keras`, and since Keras is scheduled [to support this toolkit only](https://twitter.com/fchollet/status/1174019142774452224), I am wondering what is today's use for `tf.keras.backend`. From what I can see, it exposes only a fraction of the functions available in `tf.*`, and evolves more slowly.

So, is `tf.keras.backend`

- better be avoided, because it is an obsolete remnant of the past that is likely to be dropped in a future release?
- or, a future-proof alternative to `tf.*` to be preferred whenever possible, because this API changes at a much slower pace than TF itself and is not going down anytime soon?
- or something else?

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to say either is better at this point. Because keras backend offers unique feature(s) (still).

For example, [`K.rnn`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/rnn) is a very valuable function provided by Keras backend. This can be used to iterate the temporal output of a sequential model (LSTM/GRU) on the temporal dimension. This is pretty useful when you have to do a `map()` like function on each temporal output of a sequential model (e.g. computing attention vector for each LSTM output of the encoder). This is a very convenient functions to achieve the above because, (as far as I know) doing this with `tf.*` involves `tf.gather` and can become ugly (especially in TF 1.x). I am not really sure about other functions that might offer a unique advantage over `tf.*`. But probably there are a few (e.g. [`K.foldl`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/foldl?version=stable)).

On the other hand, `tf.*` does offer many more functions than what the Keras backend offers.

In conclusion, I think it's too early to completely avoid Keras backend. But I do feel like the keras backend will get merged to `tf.*` at some point in order to offer a more consistent API.

Comment: Good call for `K.rnn`. However there is a `tf.foldl` that has been around for quite a while. I do feel also that merging `backend` to `tf` would make sense, but at the same time, I feel this could not happen because development is done by different teams with overlapping but not identical interests.

Comment: Can you explain the difference between K.rnn and implementing an rnn using a loop? Does K.rnn have performance benefits?